# Forcing IIS virtual smtp server to verify outgoing TLS certificate

Tags: email, iis, smtp, tls

I am in a situation where a web application is using the IIS virtual SMTP server to send out email.  The IIS virtual SMTP server is then configured to send all mail out through a smarthost, over TLS encryption.  This is working, except that through testing, it appears that IIS is **not** verifying the hostname it connects to in the remote certificate.  Because of this, I believe it could be possible for someone to perform a man-in-the-middle attack.  (The second SMTP relay is not located in the same datacenter, and is not connecting over a VPN).

Is there anyway to configure IIS virtual SMTP server 6.0 to verify the hostname in the outgoing TLS connection?

Thanks!